# Deleting browser (IE) cache and cookies using VBScript

Tags: cookies, vbscript

I need help deleting browser cookies and cache using VBScript.. I have tried many methods from various blogs but found useless..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. See [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8"

'To clear browsing cookies
WshShell.run "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2"

'To Clear Browsing History
WshShell.run "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1"
```

Try that.